# Powershell - EPOCH method filter by EndDate

Tags: powershell, filter, epoch

I have already asked a question on this site to find the most recent end of warranty only, I would also like to use a table with : Servicetag |EndDate and convert the warranty end dates with Epoch to get the most recent date. 
More precisely:
First step: a column with the serial numbers and another column containing the end date of the warranty (in a table). 
Second step: a column with the serial numbers and another one with the date of the end of the warranty transformed thanks to Epoch.
Thirdly extract the serial number with the highest warranty end date (epoch number). 
Fourth step: Format one column with serial number and the other column with the highest warranty end date and export it in another CSV file.
In my CSV I have this :

```
"Service Tag", "Start Date", "End Date"... 
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2016 12:59:59 "  
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2019 12:59:59 " 
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2017 12:59:59 " 
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2017 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2018 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2020 12:59:59 "
```

I'd like to have as a result:

```
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2019 12:59:59 " 
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2020 12:59:59 "
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the layout Drake perera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my version. [*grin*] the 1st section fakes reading in a CSV file. use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet when ready to use real data. the comments seem to cover what is happening. please ask for clarification if i was not clear enuf ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in the data
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
"Service Tag", "Start Date", "End Date"
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2016 12:59:59 "
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2019 12:59:59 "
"57D2D85", "12/11/2015 01:00:00 ", "12/12/2017 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2017 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2018 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85", "01/12/2016 01:00:00 ", "01/13/2020 12:59:59 "
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in the data

$Results = $InStuff |
    # sort by the "End Date" property
    #    this would be MUCH more direct without the trailing spaces in the data
    #    it would also be simpler without the silly embedded spaces in the column/property names
    Sort-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'End Date'.Trim(), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $Null)} |
    Group-Object -Property 'Service Tag' |
    ForEach-Object {
        # this grabs the last item in each group
        #    combined with the earlier "Sort-Object" it gives the newest item for each "Service Tag"
        $_.Group[-1]
        }

# on screen
$Results

# send to CSV    
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\Smarty13_ExpirationDateReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen ...

```
Service Tag Start Date           End Date            
----------- ----------           --------            
57D2D85     12/11/2015 01:00:00  12/12/2019 12:59:59 
4ZRMD85     01/12/2016 01:00:00  01/13/2020 12:59:59
```

csv file content ...

```
"Service Tag","Start Date","End Date"
"57D2D85","12/11/2015 01:00:00 ","12/12/2019 12:59:59 "
"4ZRMD85","01/12/2016 01:00:00 ","01/13/2020 12:59:59 "
```

Comment: Lee_Dailey, first of all thank you for your response. 
I tested your version first, it works well however as you said in real life I have to put: use Import-Csv.  
Only I mark :  
$Instuff = Import-csv C:\... .csv but it doesn't work. Can you tell me why? Thank you.  
(I'm commenting the region >> fake reading in the data)

Comment: @Smarty13 - you _should_ be able to [A] comment out or remove the `#region/#endregion` stuff & then [B] add `$InStuff = Import-Csv c:\Full\Path\To\Your\FIle.csv` and it should work. ///// if it does not, then what errors are you seeing? what does "doesn't work" mean in your situation?

Comment: I have a question when exporting the .csv, can we remove the "servicetag" label in the .csv?
The goal being to have only the serial numbers and not the service tag in your head. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Smarty13 - you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// the usual way to rearrange the properties in your objects is to use either `Select-Object` to give you the props you want, OR to use `[PSCustomObject]` to do the same in a slightly neater, slightly faster structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
$CleanedWarranties = Import-Csv .\warranty.csv | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[DateTime]$_."End Date"}; Ascending = $True} | Group-Object -Property "Service Tag" | foreach {($_).Group[-1]}
$CleanedWarranties | Export-Csv -Path cleanedwarranties.csv -NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content .\cleanedwarranties.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Out-File .\headerlesswarranties.csv -Encoding ASCII
```

This imports the data, sorts it all by the "End Date" property, puts them into groups based on the "Service Tag" then uses `foreach` to select only the last element of each group. Then you can get rid of the header using `Select-Object -Skip 1`.

Comment: neat! [*grin*] the only things i would change would be ... [1] test the `[datetime]` call to be sure that it would work with `dd/MM/yyyy` as the locale format. i have had to deal with EU/US/military time and find many glitches when i get one while expecting the other. [2] wrap that long 1st line so it can be read without side-scrolling. [3] i would likely also remove the trailing spaces in the sample dates before trying to parse them.

Comment: Hello, it seems to be working wonders. Thank you for your response and your research.

Comment: I have a question when exporting the .csv, can we remove the "servicetag" label in the .csv?
The goal being to have only the serial numbers and not the service tag in your head. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Smarty13 Updated!